# Dynamically adding tags in HTML document on button click immediately reversed

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

I have very simple table with 3 columns that show 2 teams and their scores. Below the table there is a form that enables adding new teams and their scores to the table. The new row should be added only when given teams have different names and scores aren't negative.

I wrote the below code in JavaScript but it doesn't add the row - it is just showing new row only when confirm button is clicked. When it's not, the data disappear.

Can you look at my code and check what may be wrong with it?

I tried to add rows to the table without validate event and it worked perfectly fine.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

var team1 = document.getElementById("team1");
var team2 = document.getElementById("team2");
var points1 = document.getElementById("points1");
var points2 = document.getElementById("points2");
var button = document.querySelector(".btn-primary");
var table = document.querySelector("table");

function validate(e) {
    if (team1.value === team2.value) {
        alert("Enter two differnt teams' names");
    } else if (points1.value < 0 || points2.value < 0) {
        alert("Points number cannot be negative");
    } else {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        table.appendChild(newRow);
        var newTeam1 = document.createElement("td");
        newRow.appendChild(newTeam1);
        newTeam1.innerHTML = team1.value;
        var newTeam2 = document.createElement("td");
        newRow.appendChild(newTeam2);
        newTeam2.innerHTML = team2.value;
        var newPoints = document.createElement("td");
        newRow.appendChild(newPoints);
        newPoints.innerHTML = points1.value + " - " + points2.value;
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", validate);
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with " it is just showing new row only when confirm button is clicked. When it's not, the data dissapear.". This is not clear to me.

Comment: @NineBerry When I enter data to the form and click submit, new data is shown in the table but only when submit is pressed

Comment: Do you mean that the added row disappears immediately or after some time or after you perform some certain other action like refreshing the browser?

Comment: They dissapear right after I stop pressing right-click on a submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the button is part of a HTML `<form>`. Clicking the button submits the form and leads to the page being reloaded.

There are three different possible solutions to the problem. use either of those:

---

1) Place the button outside the form. Remove the `<form></form>` tags if you don't need them or place the button somewhere outside the `<form></form>` tags.

---

2) Specifically mark the button as being a button that does not submit the form:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-primary">Push me</button>
```

The `type="button"` prevents the button from submitting the form.

---

3) In the javascript handler of the button tell the button to not show its default behaviour like this:

```
function validate(e) {
{
    // Your current code here       

    // Additional code to prevent button from showing default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
}
```

The `e.returnValue = false;` is for older browsers, the `e.preventDefault();` is for newer browsers.

Comment: @devnull69 I often confuse that myself, but this is only true when directly assigning an event handler like `myElement.onclick=myhandler`, but not when using `addEventListener()`.